# Is tftpd-hpa not a process in Linux?

Tags: linux, tftp

I installed tftpd-hpa and tftp in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

when I check the status of tftpd-hpa with service command, it shows running.

```
zlf@ubuntu:~$ service tftpd-hpa status
tftpd-hpa start/running
```

But when I check its process, there is no running PID to show.

```
zlf@ubuntu:~$ ps -ef |grep ftp
zlf       5607  5397  0 15:02 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto ftp
zlf@ubuntu:~$ ps -ef |grep hpa
zlf       5609  5397  0 15:02 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto hpa
```

what happened? Is tftpd-hpa not a process or other reason?

By the way, I test tftpd-hpa by localhost, it doesn't work.

```
zlf@ubuntu:~$ tftp localhost
tftp> get test
Transfer timed out.
```

Comment: thank you @Dan, you really have rocket speed for edit.

Answer (score 1):

TFTP requests are probably handled by inetd/xinetd.